# "And" in numbers

Tags: numbers

Are the "ands" optional in AmE?

1,475 = one thousand, four hundred and seventy-five.

105,375 = one hundred and five thousand, three hundred and seventy-five.

304,102,375 = three hundred and four million, one hundred and two thousand, three hundred and seventy-five.

Comment: I think omitting the "and"s may be even be *preferred* in AmE, even though "and" is mandatory in BrE.

Comment: Then English File isn't quite right. It asks to correct the mistakes. 175 it says "a hundred seventy-five."  A/one both are used in BrE. It doesn't have an "and"  but it can be omitted in AmE. So it's not really "a mistake". Or in 3,009. It says "three thousand nine". "And" should be used in BrE but  is optional in AmE so not writing "and" is not a mistake in AmE.

Comment: That's correct.  Missing out the "and" wouldn't be a mistake in AmE.  See also https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/48455/should-i-add-and-before-last-number

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the US AND should ONLY be used when there is a Decimal point, as in dollars & cents

For example: $200.02 =two hundred dollars and two cents
200.002 = two hundred AND two Thousandths
202,000 = two hundred two thousand
.202  =  two hundred two  Thousandths   ( no and !! )

Also by the same rule there should be NO AND's in any years:
2001 = two thousand one
2010 = two thousand ten
2020 = two thousand twenty  ( no one would ever say 19 and 99 )